# Is a user thread spawned by a daemon thread continue to live after all other user threads are completed?

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

By documentation:

> If all users thread are completed, all daemon threads are abruptly stopped and program is over, and until at least 1 user thread is alive the program is alive.

So the intuitive answer on my question:
"Is a user thread spawned by a daemon thread continue to live after all other user threads are completed?" 
is: **it continues to live**.

But I heard the contrary opinion, help, please

Comment: The type of a thread (daemon / non-daemon) is not dependent upon the type of the thread it was started from, so your question is based upon a false premise.

Comment: A non-daemon thread started by any thread can keep the application alive.

Comment: Also, that quote is not from the documentation. The statement "until at least 1 user thread is alive" does not make sense (it should be "*while* at least 1 user thread...")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a non-daemon thread continues running if other non-daemon threads are finished. It is irrelevant as to how the non-daemon thread was created, i.e. whether the creating thread was daemon or not.